# Memory leak when changing a value that indicates an index in a computed property

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am having issues with a computed property

```
correctAnswersForCurrentStage(): object {return 
    return this.correctAnswers[this.currentLevel] ?? {};
},
```

Some context:
this.correctAnswers is an object where the properties are the levels and the values are object for each gate:

```
this.correctAnswers = {
     "1": {
        "1": 15,
        "2": 25,
        "3": 35,
        "4": 45
    },
    "2": {
        "1": 15,
        "2": 25,
        "3": 35,
        "4": 45
    },
}
```

so when a level is finished, i increase the level like

```
this.currentLevel++
```

and after this everything blocks. I don't know if it's Vue or TypeScript that gives this problem. Or maybe the combination of both?
Anyone an idea why this happens?

I tried turning off the increasing of levels and then i don't have an issue. Obviously i keep playing on the same level. But the other reset logic works

Follow up:

when i change it so that it doesn't need work with an index i keep having the same issue now i made it:

```
correctAnswersForCurrentStage(): object {
    if (this.currentLevel === 1) {
        return this.correctAnswersForLevel1;
    }
    if (this.currentLevel === 2) {
        return this.correctAnswersForLevel2;
    }
    if (this.currentLevel === 3) {
        return this.correctAnswersForLevel3;
    }
    if (this.currentLevel === 4) {
        return this.correctAnswersForLevel4;
    }
    return {};
},
```

Comment: is the `return` in the separate line from the returned value as you've here?

Comment: i'm sorry i see i messed up with the code fragment the return is the same line as getting the answers. I'll change the code fragment

Comment: Fixed it. It had nothing to do with above stuff. i oversaw some logic in generating the random wrong answers

scenario: Min was set to 5, max to 10. so it had 5 numbers to choose from. level too had 6 and 9 for correct answers. so it only had 3 unused more options left. and i asked it to give me 4 that are not already used

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell with the currently provided code, but I suspect that `this.correctAnswersForLevel1` etc are also computed properties. This would mean you get a circular reference which results in an endless loop.

Aside from that, the code contains wrong references:
`this.correctAnswers['1']` is not the same as `this.correctAnswers[1]` as this compares strings and numbers with each other.